PHP-ZIP extension is missing on your server. Please install the extension
I have that error in this part of the code:
`
 if (!extension_loaded('zip')) {
            return Reply::error('<b>PHP-ZIP</b> extension is missing on your server. Please install the extension.');
        }

The zip extension doesn't grab me, what I'm trying to do is install a laravel-modules package in Laravel. I already have the zip and I try to install it and it doesn't pass that verification:
I already tried, uncomment ;extension=zip from the php.ini
But the error is still there.
I use Windows 10
How do I install php-ini in my work environment

After the php.ini edit, did you restart the webserver?
